# Why these credits for Star Trek Into Darkness?

Tags: character, credits, star-trek, star-trek-into-darkness

I noticed during the credit sequence at the end of Star Trek Into Darkness that Chris Hemsworth and Jennifer Morrison were credited as Kirk's parents (whom they portrayed in the previous film).

I cannot recall seeing them, either as a flashback or as an audio bite, in this new film.

Can anyone shed any light on this? A deleted scene?

Comment: Were they in the audience during his speech at the end?

Comment: @Flimzy not sure about his mother but I doubt it given what happened to George Kirk in the 1st film!

Comment: I wondered briefly if we heard their voices during Kirk's 'coma dream' at the end - but then that wouldn't make any sense as he had never heard his dad's voice.

Comment: I imagine that they filmed scenes (memories?) which were later cut.

Comment: You might be right, Dan. I guess this one remains un-answerable until the DVD comes out...

Comment: he heard their voices because he died, he was being reborn...hence he heard their voices like the first time when he was born...YEAH I like that Idea!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to an [article](http://trekmovie.com/2013/05/18/snls-bill-hader-has-star-trek-into-darkness-voice-cameo-more-tidbits-from-cast-credits/) about the credits for the movie at TrekMovie.com,

> although they [Hemsworth and Morrison] don’t appear in the film, some of their dialog from the 2009 movie can be briefly heard during a dream sequence/flashback.

Presumably that counts as a speaking part, so they have to be in the credits.

Comment: As I thought. Which makes it rather ridiculous as it was Kirk's dream sequence and yet he hears his father's voice? Ah well, good digging.

Comment: Maybe he'd heard recordings of his father's voice?

Answer (score 11):

At the end of the film, Kirk is slowly regaining consciousness.  During this scene, some audio from *Star Trek (2009)* plays.  It's from the opening sequence of that film, when his parents were discussing naming him.  You hear both Chris Hemsworth's and Jennifer Morrison's voices, and so that's why they're credited.

No, it doesn't make sense that he'd be hearing this, he was just born in that scene, so he couldn't possibly remember this.

Comment: Yep - just watched it again and noticed the voices. Cheers.